# What tense is used in the sentence? Why it is "would have had" rather than "would have"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense

The sentence is:

> Hardware specifications rapidly become obsolete, but for the sake of illustration, a typical choice of machine for running an HDFS datanode and a YARN node manager in 2014 **would have had** the following specifications:
>   *somespec*

So it looks like Third Conditional, which, in turn, is used when "both the condition and result are impossible now.", but it doesn't looks *impossible* to me. How meaning would had changed if it had have been just "would have"?

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact the third conditional. The confusion lies in having two different uses of the verb *have*.  First, *have* (and *would*) are auxiliary verbs used to denote the conditional mood.  Second, *have* is also a verb in its own right meaning "possess."  So you have the verb *have* in the past (third) conditional.

Have a look at these:

> The machine has the following specifications.
>   The machine would have the following specifications.

Here we are using the verb *have* in its "ordinary" sense.  The first sentence is present tense, the second is present (second) conditional.

Now, look at these:

> The machine had the following specifications.
>   The machine would have had the following specifications.

The first sentence is past tense, again using the verb *have* in its "ordinary" sense.  The second is past (third) conditional.  The *have* in the second sentence is an auxiliary verb which is used with *would* in the past conditional.  But the word *had* in the second sentence is again a use of the verb "have" in its "ordinary" sense. The "ordinary" sense of the verb has nothing to do with the structure of the conditional.  The fact that it is the same verb is coincidental.

To further clarify this, have a look at these analogous sentences, with the verb *feature* substituted for the verb *have*:

> The machine featured the following specifications.
>   The machine would have featured the following specifications.

You can see that the word *have* in the last sentence is again an auxiliary verb used as part of setting up the past conditional tense.